# Is there a way to filter a list of union types in Elm without explict case/pattern matching?

Tags: elm

I've got a list of things and I want to filter based on a Union type.  simplified, it might be something like this:

```ml
type Groceries =
  Apples
  | Cheese
  | Widgets

shoppingList = [Apples, Cheese, Cheese, Widgets, Apples]
```

is there a nice syntax for filtering all the elements that match a particular subtype?

```
# idk, eg
fruit = shoppingList |> List.filter =Apple?
```

I know i can use a lambda with a `case` statement but it seems so verbose!

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
fruit = shoppingList |> List.filter ((==) Apples)
```

`(==)` takes the infix equals operator and treats it as an ordinary function. Then, applying `Apples` to it will return a partially applied function that compares whatever is applied to it to `Apples`.

However, this will only work on simple variants that can be directly compared.